# Enable textView above fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, textview

How can i be able to enable this textView on top of the fragment. I want it to remain static even when fragments change from one another. Iam having no luck enabling it on top. Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.skwebviewapp.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.skwebviewapp.MainActivity”
    android:orientation=“vertical"
    android:weightSum=“1.0">


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height=“0dp”
        android:layout_weight=“0.10"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/app_name”/>


     <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=“0dp"
        android:layout_weight=“0.90"
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this with RelativeLayout.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_view_fargment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This puts it inside the fragment. I want it to display on top of the fragment